# Adjust space between the footnote number and the footnote text in cls in Latex?

Tags: footnotes

In my school Latex template, the space between the footnote number and the footnote text was too close, so I wanted to make it wider.
When I used these codes before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
```

It showed error for there is a **cls** file in the folder which controls the footnote style.

Then I opened the cls and I found these codes which may be related to the footnote style. But, I don't know how to adjust it for I can't understand **cls**. I hope to add `~` between the footnote number the footnote text.

```
\tl_set:Nn \@makefnmark
  {
    \kern \c_zero_dim \textsuperscript { \circled { \@thefnmark } }
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand { \@makefntext } { m }
  {
    \noindent \hangindent 1 em \circled { \@thefnmark } #1 \hangafter 1
  }

\skip_set_eq:NN \headheight \baselineskip
\skip_set_eq:NN \footskip   \baselineskip

\dim_set:Nn \footnotesep { 6 pt }
\setlength { \skip \footins } { \skip_eval:n { 2 \baselineskip } plus 1 fill }
\tl_set:Nn \footnotesize { \songti \zihao { 5 } }
\tl_set:Nn \footnoterule
  { \noindent \rule [ 1 pt ] { 0.3 \columnwidth } { 1 pt } }

\NewDocumentCommand { \circled } { m }
  {
    \resizebox { 1 em } { ! }
      {
        \tikz [ baseline = ( char.base ) ]
          {
            \node [ shape = circle , draw , inner ~ sep = \c_zero_dim ,
              minimum ~ size = 1 em ] ( char ) {#1};
          } 
      }
  }
```

May you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you please expand your code, so that we can just copy&compile it? Please make sure to include your problem AND omit uneccessary code. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO Hi, I never check **cls** file before. I don't know what code is necessary. I searched on Google who showed that I should modify the code from **\tl_set:Nn \@makefnmark**. I even don't know what decide the space between the footnote number and the foottext in the code.

Comment: "When I used these codes before \begin{document}: ..." Just complete the preamble, put some text after \begin{document} till its \end, include a footnote and make sure your error shows up. Next, add this code to your question.

Comment: @MS-SPO This template is one of China's universities. There are two many Chinese codes. I am afraid it will be hard to read.

Comment: I understand. However, who could answer you question without knowing more details? As indication, flagging a cls file is unusual. Ok, I'll prepare an example which you could apply to your text to further localise your error of any kind. See you soon.

Comment: @MS-SPO This link can download all the code: https://github.com/whutug/whu-thesis/archive/refs/tags/v0.6d.zip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135467/discussion-between-y-zeng-and-ms-spo).

Answer (score 1):

According to our conversation it's difficult to post code in chinese langugae here. As promissed I'll give you a guide, which can help you to track down the error.

This code is similar to one recently posted, and it contains an error; it may not be the best example, but you should get the idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\foo\textit

\begin{document}

\section{Command \foo{aliasing}}
Here I use \texttt{\textbackslash foo} to
\foo{to typeset this in italic}.

\end{document}
```

Here are the errors:
[image]

Let's pretend the indications aren't helpful enough. What to do?

STRATEGY: split the code into "half", so each part still can compile, and compile both. Check for errors. Repeat with the reduced version, which contains the error, until you can spot it.

IDEA: "half1" = content, "half2" = preamble

So this one passes, after including some text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\foo\textit

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

"half2": removing the hyperref and the \let part compiles with (a different) error.

So let's split the preamble into "half" again. This one compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\foo\textit

\begin{document}

\section{Command \foo{aliasing}}
Here I use \texttt{\textbackslash foo} to
\foo{to typeset this in italic}.

\end{document}
```

while this one doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\let\foo\textit

\begin{document}

\section{Command \foo{aliasing}}
Here I use \texttt{\textbackslash foo} to
\foo{to typeset this in italic}.

\end{document}
```

It can't because the definition used was removed.

So, time to analyse the new insights. In this setting "\usepackage{hyperref}" is a trouble maker. The code in itself might need improvement, but at least you found a way to continue: exclude this package.

I'm sure, if you try this strategy on copies of your code you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hello,  I did as the post I posted first. The error is **Option clash for package footmisc.**